# Blender 4.0 compositing add a subscribe green screen to the end of a movie clip

Tags: compositing-nodes

I can see how to add my short "subscribe" green screen clip to my video in compositing but I can't figure out how to  move it to the end of the video.
Maybe there is another way to add it without compositing?
Again this is blender  4.0.